# Can I use javascript to uppercase the first letter from the prompt input

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I was wondering a way of upper-casing the first letter, my code is:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
if (userChoice !== "Rock" || userChoice !== "Paper" || userChoice !== "Scissors") {
   throw new Error("Incorrect choice.");
};
```

I want it so that regardless if the user enters "Rock, ROCK or rock" etc... it still accepts it; I am not sure if this is the best way about it though.

I am learning JS by just practising so any help would be great.

Comment: Take a look at [String.prototype.toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Comment: there is no need to make it lower or upper case. it would even work without that.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya - how do you figure? `rock != Rock` no matter how you twist it ?

Comment: @adeneo oh sorry! it's my bad it wont work..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compare against lowercase version of the entered string:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?").toLowerCase();
if (userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors") {
    throw new Error("Incorrect choice.");
};
```

Also the logic has a mistake: you need to use `&&` operator, not `||`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it just returns "Error: Incorrect choice." Regardless of the choice i make.

Comment: Also there is another mistake: you need to use `&&` operator, not `||`. Check updated answer.